# Can I replicate the `strings` command using `grep`?

Tags: grep, git-bash

I often use a Windows Git Bash environment, which doesn't contain the [`strings`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/strings.1.html) command.

Is is it possible to use a tool like [`grep`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/grep.1posix.html) to output all the strings of ASCII or printable characters above a certain length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do give all ASCII/printable characters, each on a separate line :

```
grep -o '[ -~]*' input > output
```

To further grep for strings of minimal length 10, you could use:

```
grep -x '.\{10,\}' input >output
```

Where the `-x` switch denotes a whole-line match.

Piping the first command into the second one will approximate
the `strings` search for strings of a minimal length:

```
grep -o '[ -~]*' input | grep -x '.\{10,\}' >output
```

Or as one grep command :

```
grep -o '[ -~]\{10,\}' input > output
```

Comment: Thanks.  How does the second command affect the output of the first?  Does it just ensure a minimum match length?

Comment: I added the example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  But the reason I ask is, if it's just about ensuring a minimum match length, could the two greps be combined into one?

Comment: The `-x` parameter would not work with the first grep.

Comment: I mean, I think you've given me the key components here - using `[ -~]` to filter printable characters, and `\{10,\}` to match 10 or more of them.  But can't those two things be combined directly?

Comment: You're right : `grep -o '[ -~]\{10,\}'`